# Tkinter How to set focus from a function

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to set the focus to *entry_1* in a function, but *entry_2* gets the focus. What's wrong?

```
import tkinter as tk


def _test_entry(event):
    if value_1.get() == 'a':
        entry_1.focus_set()


win = tk.Tk()
win.geometry("200x100")

value_1 = tk.StringVar(value='')

entry_1 = tk.Entry(win, textvariable=value_1)
entry_1.bind("<Tab>", _test_entry)
entry_1.pack()

entry_2 = tk.Entry(win)
entry_2.pack()

entry_1.focus_set()
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: You need to end your event handler with `return "break"` - otherwise, the builtin binding for `<Tab>` gets invoked, and moves the focus to the next widget that can accept it.